# Cannot get React-Bootstrap cards to show next to eachother

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5, mern

I am creating a price comparison website and have data stored in MongoDB. I've been able to get the data needed to show on my frontend, however, the data will not show side by side.
I am using Bootstrap Cards to show the data.

The code I have so far:

paintDetails.js

```
import { Button, Card, Row, Col, Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useAuthContext } from '../hooks/useAuthContext';

const PaintDetails = ({ paint }) => {

const { user } = useAuthContext();

return (
        <Container fluid>
            <Row lg={4}>
                <Col className='d-flex'>
                    <Card className='bg-info mx-auto m-2 flex-fill'>
                        <Card.Body>
                            <Card.Img variant='top' src={paint.paintImage} alt="Paint Image" height="50%" width="100%" />
                                <div className="paint-details">
                                    <Card.Title className='text-center pt-2'>{paint.paintTitle} - {paint.paintCompany}</Card.Title>
                                    <p><strong>Type: </strong>{paint.paintType}</p>
                                    <p><strong>Prices: </strong></p>
                                    <ul>
                                        <a href={paint.paintLink.elementLink} target="_blank" rel='noreferrer'><li>Element Games: {paint.paintPrice.elementPrice}</li></a>
                                        <a href={paint.paintLink.waylandLink} target="_blank" rel='noreferrer'><li>Wayland Games: {paint.paintPrice.waylandPrice}</li></a>
                                        <a href={paint.paintLink.hobbyworkshopPrice} target="_blank" rel='noreferrer'><li>Hobby Workshop: {paint.paintPrice.hobbyworkshopPrice}</li></a>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                    {user && (
                                    <div className="buttons">
                                            
                                        <Button variant='primary'>Add to inventory</Button>
                                        <Button variant='primary'>Add to wishlist</Button>
                                                
                                    </div>
                                        )}
                        </Card.Body>
                    </Card>
                </Col>      
            </Row>
        </Container>  
)
}


export default PaintDetails;
```

citadelPage.js

```
import React from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";

import { usePaintsContext } from '../hooks/usePaintContext.js';

import PaintDetails from "../components/PaintDetails.js";



export default function CitadelPage() {

const {paints, dispatch} = usePaintsContext()

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPaints = async () => {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/citadel' 
        )
        const json = await response.json()

        if (response.ok) {
            dispatch({type: 'SET_PAINTS', payload: json})
        }
    }

    fetchPaints()

}, [dispatch])

return (
    <>
        <h1 className="title text-center">Citadel Paint</h1>
        
                <Container className="border border-primary rounded bg-secondary">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="paints">
                            {paints && paints.map((paint) => (
                                <PaintDetails key={paint._id} paint={paint} />
                            ))}
                        </div>
                    </div>        

                </Container>

    </>        
)
}
```

However, the cards only show in a single column. I have tried added various Bootstrap classes to the  and  such as lg={4} etc. However, none of these seem to work.

Thanks in advance for any support.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who may come across this, I was able to fix it by using the following code:

paintDetails.js

```
import { Button, Card, Row, Col, Container} from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useAuthContext } from '../hooks/useAuthContext';
import { usePaintsContext } from '../hooks/usePaintContext.js';

const PaintDetails = ({ paint }) => {

const { user } = useAuthContext();
const { paints } = usePaintsContext();




return (

    <Row lg={4}>
        {paints &&
            paints.map((product) => {
            const { id, paintTitle, paintType, paintImage, paintCompany, elementLink, waylandLink, hobbyworkshopLink, elementPrice, waylandPrice, hobbyworkshopPrice } = product;
            return (
                <Container>
                <Col className="d-flex">
                    <Card className="flex-fill bg-info mx-auto m-2 flex-fill" key={id}>
                        <Card.Body>
                            <Card.Img variant='top' src={paintImage} alt="Paint Image" height="50%" width="100%" />
                                <div className="paint-details">
                                    <Card.Title className='text-center pt-2'>{paintTitle} - {paintCompany}</Card.Title>
                                    <p><strong>Type: </strong>{paintType}</p>
                                    <p><strong>Prices: </strong></p>
                                    <ul>
                                        <a href={elementLink} target="_blank" rel='noreferrer'><li>Element Games: {elementPrice}</li></a>
                                        <a href={waylandLink} target="_blank" rel='noreferrer'><li>Wayland Games: {waylandPrice}</li></a>
                                        <a href={hobbyworkshopLink} target="_blank" rel='noreferrer'><li>Hobby Workshop: {hobbyworkshopPrice}</li></a>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                    {user && (
                                    <div className="buttons">
                                                
                                        <Button variant='primary'>Add to inventory</Button>
                                        <Button variant='primary'>Add to wishlist</Button>
                                                    
                                        </div>
                                            )}
                        </Card.Body>
                    </Card>
                </Col>
                </Container>
            );
            })}
    </Row> 
)
}


export default PaintDetails;
```

CitadelPage.js

```
import React from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";

import { usePaintsContext } from '../hooks/usePaintContext.js';

import PaintDetails from "../components/PaintDetails.js";
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap';



export default function CitadelPage() {

const { dispatch} = usePaintsContext()

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPaints = async () => {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/citadel')
        const json = await response.json()

        if (response.ok) {
            dispatch({type: 'SET_PAINTS', payload: json})
        }
    }

    fetchPaints()

}, [dispatch])

return (
    <>

    <h1 className="title text-center">Citadel Paint</h1>

    <Container className="border border-primary rounded bg-secondary">
        <PaintDetails />
    </Container>

    </>        
)
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).